# Fire a function when all hot modules are loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

I want to fire a function when all scripts are loaded in my react app. My app uses hot loaders (react-hot-loader). How do fire some event when all script on a page are loaded and executed. Thank you!

I load the modules/components like:

`export const Root = hot(RootUnwrapped);`

Answer (score 0):

If we looking in documentation we see:

- (that's the goal) React-Hot-Loader would not change the past, only
  update the present - no lifecycle event would be called on component
  update. As a result - all the code changes, you may made among
  componentWillUnmount or componentDidMount, would be ignored for
  already created components.
- (that's the goal) React-Hot-Loader would not update any object,
  including component state.

But, as we know, hot loader resets state.

So, you can get one of lifecycle methods that allows you to check old and new state. 
If the state is reset to the init state, it was Hot-Loader.

P.S. But, if your goal is check when your app is first loaded, you can do it in constructor of root component.